# xlwings spreadsheet calculation differs whether excel is visible (open) or not visible

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I have a model in excel with formula that's very complex. For the purposes of this exercise, I'm trying to run xlwings in python to be able to input a variable into another cell which feeds this formula, and return the output back into python.

I am able to get the code working two ways: (1) where it runs an excel instance in the background so that the application doesn't launch, inputs the variable, reads the result and displays it in python, and (2) where it launches the model in excel on my desktop, inputs the variable, reads the result and displays it in python.

My problem: the result displayed in python are two different numbers... usually very close to each other. When I load excel and input the variable myself, the result matches what I get with method (2), however, I'm trying to avoid launching excel altogether otherwise I would do it manually (not scalable).

I have suspicion that there's something with the xw.App line, but I'm stumped as to why

P.S. also the methods tend to produce the same value when the excel formula is very simple (i.e. = A1 + 10), but vary when the formula is rather complex (i.e. =((P55*(1-'EPA RVO'!O28))+(P61*(1-'EPA RVO'!O27)))*42*365*P$66/(10^6) )

```
import xlwings as xw
import pandas as pd
import time

excel_app = xw.App(visible=False)
# excel_book = excel_app.books.open('xlwings_test.xlsx')  #method (1)

excel_book = xw.Book('xlwings_test.xlsx') #method (2)
time.sleep(15)

#define sheet
test_sheet = excel_book.sheets['Sheet1']

#define inputs
test_sheet.cells(1, 'A').value = 5

#locate result
table = test_sheet.range('A1:B1').value

#return result
pd.DataFrame(table)

#close book and instance 
excel_book.close()
excel_app.quit()
```